# How to test callback that uses parent record in Rspec Feature spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a feature spec to create an `order`. That `order` has a callback like so:

```
class Order
  belongs_to :site
  before_validation :add_call_number

  def add_call_number
    self.call_number = self.site.call_number_start
  end
end
```

In the spec, I get a NoMethod error on `call_number_start`, because `self.site` doesn't exist.

I discovered that the `Site` I created in the Rspec before action doesn't exist at all. In other words...

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe "create successfully", type: :feature, js: true do
  before do
    @site = create(:site)
    visit "/orders"
    .... # various actions to build an order using the page's form
    puts ">>>>>"
    puts "site in before action: #{Site.all.size}"
    find("#checkoutModal #submit").click()
    sleep(1)
  end
  it "should create" do
    expect(Order.all.size).to equal(1)
    expect(Order.last.call_number).to equal(@site.call_number_start)
  end
end

# controller action that #submit POSTs to
def create
  puts ">>>>>"
  puts "site in controller create: #{Site.all.size}"
  puts ">>>"
  puts "site_id from order_params: #{order_params[:site_id]}"
  @order = Order.new(order_params)
  @order.save if @order.valid?
end

def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(:site_id)
end

# puts output:
>>>>>
site in before action: 1
>>>>>
site in controller create: 0
>>>
site_id from order_params: 1
```

I thought this was a database cleaner issue, so I went really pedantically to manually set it up as `truncation` method like this:

```
# rails_helper.rb

Rspec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, js: true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each, truncate: true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

How can I correctly test this callback?

Comment: This is still esseentially the same as your old question. To even have a chance at answering this we need to see the code under test.

Comment: ok sorry about that, I have added a little more detail. what other code would you like to see? I'm happy to include whatever, just trying to avoid the clutter if I pasted in all the view and routes, and such like that.

Answer (score 0):

You created a site but did not give it to order in the controller.

Is the site coming from `order_params` in Controller? Then figure out in controller why site is not available.

Is the site an association with the order? Then need to create the site for order:

```rb
FactoryBot.create(:site, order: order)
```

Comment: i updated, yes the `site_id` is coming from `order_params`. site is an order's parent. Your question is exactly right... as you can see in the controller the site isn't available, and I don't know why

Comment: The site_id is either coming from params (field of form in the view), or the URL /:site_id/. Check which one and find why it‘s missing.

Comment: but it's not missing, so you can see from my `puts` statement above that it is in fact sending via `order_params`